# API/opendata for public companies 10Q

Tags: data-request, finance, api

I have a list of public companies that I need to pull the `revenue` and `operating income` from their quarter report. I don't have that much finance background, but all the 10Q looks very similar in the format but not exactly the same(some have netincome, the other might use netprofit).

That list of companies is really big and this will be an ongoing process that need to be schedule every quarter.

Is there any restful API available that I can use? or any open data that I don't have to go through the 10Q one by one.

Comment: Could you please post a short extract of the list? Does it look like "トヨタ自動車株式会社、みずほ銀行" or like "39235,86935" or like "MSO,MDP"? Depending on that, how to get the information will be different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get private companies' financials?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/where-can-i-get-private-companies-financials)

Comment: Not very familiar with this, but for companies that submit 10Q as XBRL that you find at US SEC EDGAR, aren't those values in there? Or else the inputs to calculate them?