# Where to find number of companies by year revenue?

Tags: data-request, economics, business

I'm trying to find number of companies which reach a certain scale of revenue per year. For example in USA is `x` companies with revenue $100k-$1M, `y` companies with revenue $1M-$10M, `z` companies in bucket $10M-$100M. I need those numbers for various regions as for USA, north amerika and Europe to begin with. Every tax agency in every modern country has to know required data. I have tried tens different queries in Google and Wolfram Alpha with zero success. Not only I can't find this data for some region but I can't find it for any region at all. I got tons of articles with a list of top 500, 1000, and so on names of biggest companies and their revenue, but they are exactly what I don't want. I'm interested in much smaller ones. Obviously I don't know the right place or the right question to ask. Can you please point me to the right direction where to find right source of such data?

Comment: Private companies aren't required to disclose their revenue to the public, so getting this data in a systematic way will be tough (in 2015).

Comment: I'm not requesting it from private companies. They have to disclose it to the tax offices. I expect the statistic from the government. The has to know the data. I don't need to know which company has the exact amount of revenue. I just want to know how many has revenue in which range. It is the huge difference. Isn't there the law in US which mandates the government to disclose the data which taxpayers already paid for?

Comment: For the USA you can check out http://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats-Table-5-Returns-of-Active-Corporations. I'm not sure about sources for other North American or European data.

Answer (score 3):

### Government procurement systems

See this answer for details on how to get the revenue numbers for firms supplying goods to governments:

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/5149/1052

Though this sample may be biased (government consumption is somewhat unconventional), this data is just two minutes away.

### Request data from a government agency

If you need only the bins by size without disclosing the names of the companies, you may send a request to IRS, BLS, or another agency that may have the data, from their surveys.